# Create a generic comparator when classes are not related to each other but have a common property on which sorting is required

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a custom comparator in java that can take different types of classes and sort by a particular method (which will be the same across all the classes). **These classes are not related to each other and inheritance can't be applied to them.**

For instance, suppose I have 2 classes Car and Bike, and both of them have a getter method which gives the count of how many of that particular vehicle has been sold. Now I want to sort a list of the particular vehicle based on this parameter.

```
public class Car {



private int selledUnits;

...



public int getSelledUnits() {

    return selledUnits;

  }

}



public class Bike {

private int selledUnits;

...



public int getSelledUnits() {

    return selledUnits;

  }

  ...

}
```

Now, suppose I have `List<Car> cars` and `List<Bike> bikes` and I want to sort these cars based on `selledUnits` field.

Currently, I am sorting by creating different comparators for a different class .

For example, for Car, I have created below comparator for sorting

```
class CarComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {

return c1.selledUnits - c2.selledUnits;

}

}
```

Similarly for sorting list of bikes below comparator is used :

```
class BikeComparator implements Comparator<Bike> {

public int compare(Bike b1, Bike b2) {

return b1.selledUnits - b2.selledUnits;

}

}
```

My question is instead of creating a separate comparator for each of these classes can I create a generic comparator, since both of them are sorting based on the same fields.

I have tried creating a generic comparator by using reflection and it is working fine but wanted to create the same without using reflection.

Comment: You should extract the ommon parts into an interface. Then you can make a comparator based on that interface.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I cannot create a common interface, as specified in the bold part above in the question

Comment: *For instance, suppose I have 2 classes Car and Bike, and both of them have a getter method which gives the count of how many of that particular vehicle has been sold.* Wrong place. Why would an instance of a vehicle have any knowledge of other instances of its kind? Only a class like, say, `VehicleSeller` would or should know that.

Comment: Then the most common type is `Object`. Make a `Comparator<Object>`. You could check whether the compared types match the types you expect in the `compare` method.

Comment: Your bold part only says that inheritance can't be used between them, but why can't they all implement an interface?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible without reflection or introducing a common interface.

Comment: One more option could be a wrapper class, which would expose different fields of different methods to be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parent class.
Like this one =>

```
class Parent{
 int sellingUnit;
 String name;
}

class Bike extends Parent{
 Bike(int a,String n){
    sellingUnit = a;
    name=n;
 }
}

class Car extends Parent{
 Car(int a ,String n){
    sellingUnit = a;
    name=n;
 }
}

class MainComparator{

 //sort by name
 static Comparator<Parent> sortByName() {
    return new Comparator<Parent>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Parent p1, Parent p2) {
            return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
        }
    };
 }

 //sort by selling unit
 static Comparator<Parent> sortBySellingUnit() {
    return new Comparator<Parent>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Parent p1, Parent p2) {
            return p1.sellingUnit-p2.sellingUnit;
        }
    };
 }

}

public class Myy {  

 public void display(Parent p[], String type) {
    for(Parent e:p) {
        System.out.println(type+" name "+e.name+" selling unit "+e.sellingUnit);
    }
 }

 public static void main(String asd[]) throws Exception
 {
    MainComparator comparator=new MainComparator();
    Myy my=new Myy();
    
    //testing bike
    Bike b[]=new Bike[4];
    b[0]=new Bike(1,"b1");
    b[1]=new Bike(2,"b2");
    b[2]=new Bike(4,"b4");
    b[3]=new Bike(3,"b3");
    
    System.out.println("before sorting by selling unit");
    my.display(b, "bike");
    
    Arrays.sort(b,comparator.sortBySellingUnit());
    
    System.out.println("after sorting");
    my.display(b, "bike");
    
    //car testing
    Car c[]=new Car[3];
    c[0]=new Car(10,"c1");
    c[1]=new Car(30,"c3");
    c[2]=new Car(20,"c2");
    
    System.out.println("before sorting car by name");
    my.display(c,"car");
    
    Arrays.sort(c, comparator.sortByName());
    System.out.println("after sorting car by name");
    my.display(c, "car");
    
    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has a built in comparator for comparing objects by mapping to int. It is generic.

```
List<Bike> bikes;
List<Car> cars;
//populated etc.
bikes.sort( Comparator.comparingInt( item ->  item.selledUnits ) );
cars.sort( Comparator.comparingInt( item -> item.selledUnits ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you could achieve it using a wrapper:

```
class NotVehicleException extends  RuntimeException {}

class VehicleWrapper{

    Object wrappedVehicle;

    public VehicleWrapper(Car wrappedVehicle) {
        this.wrappedVehicle = wrappedVehicle;
    }

    public VehicleWrapper(Bike wrappedVehicle) {
        this.wrappedVehicle = wrappedVehicle;
    }

    public int getSelledUnits() {
            if(wrappedVehicle instanceof Car)
                return ((Car) wrappedVehicle).getSelledUnits(); 
            else if ( wrappedVehicle instanceof Bike) 
                return ((Bike) wrappedVehicle).getSelledUnits();
            else throw new NotVehicleException();
        }
    }

class VehicleComparator implements Comparator<VehicleWrapper>{
    public int compare(VehicleWrapper b1, VehicleWrapper b2) {

        return b1.getSelledUnits() - b2.getSelledUnits();

    }

}
```

Of course, this won't give you the flexibility and elegance which you would achieve having a common class or interface, so every time you add another Vehicle type - you'll have to update the wrapper. But in general, wrappers are a common solution to bind the unbound.

Comment: Using an if-else-if structure would probably be more readable than nested ternary operators.

Comment: totally agree, just typed it fast :)

Comment: Some day we may be able to use switch expressions here: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406

Comment: You could just make the comparator compare Objects, do your class checking, and not have a wrapping class at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Without reflection is not possible.**

You can do anything at runtime using reflection.

Probably you **should not** do this but you can compare totally different objects only (e.g.) taking in account the name of the fields (you can of course take in account any other information like, if one is an `Integer` and other a `Double` do the required conversion and so on).

Define an annotation for available "sorting" fields:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ComparableField {
}
```

Let two totally indepent classes to sort together:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Car {
    private int id;
    @ComparableField
    private String name;
    @ComparableField
    private int sales;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Bike {
    private int id;
    @ComparableField
    private String name;
    @ComparableField
    private int stock;
}
```

note both share the `name` field but not the `sales` and `stock` fields.

We can force to compare any field using a weird generic comparator:

```
private static Comparator<? super Object> genericFieldComparator(String field) {
    return (a, b) -> {
        Method fa = getMethods(a.getClass()).stream().filter(f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("get" + field)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        Method fb = getMethods(b.getClass()).stream().filter(f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("get" + field)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        try {
            Object va = fa == null ? null : fa.invoke(a);
            Object vb = fb == null ? null : fb.invoke(b);
            if (va != null)
                return unsafeCompare((Comparable<Object>) va, vb);
            if (vb != null)
                return -unsafeCompare((Comparable<Object>) vb, va);
            return 0;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // cannot compare
            throw new RuntimeException("argh!");
        }
    };
}

private static <B, A extends Comparable<B>> int unsafeCompare(A a, B b) {
    return b == null ? -1 : a.compareTo(b);
}
```

with this, sort any list is simply as

```
private static Stream<Object> sortUsingField(List<Object> objects, String field) {
    return objects.stream().sorted(genericFieldComparator(field));
}
```

for example if we run

```
List<Object> objects = asList(
        new Car(1, "Audi", 300),
        new Bike(2, "MX", 30),
        new Car(3, "M Benz", 250),
        new Bike(4, "BH", 45)
);

// list possible fields to compare in runtime
System.out.printf("Available sorting fields:%n");
List<String> fields = objects.stream().flatMap(o ->
        getAllFields(o.getClass(), withAnnotation(ComparableField.class)).stream().map(Field::getName))
        .distinct()
        .peek(f -> System.out.printf(" - %s%n", f))
        .collect(toList());

// sort using every field
for (String field : fields) {
    System.out.printf("Sorting using `%s`:%n", field);
    sortUsingField(objects, field).forEach(o -> System.out.printf(" - %s%n", o));
}
```

we get

```
Available sorting fields:
 - name
 - sales
 - stock
Sorting using `name`:
 - Car(id=1, name=Audi, sales=300)
 - Bike(id=4, name=BH, stock=45)
 - Car(id=3, name=M Benz, sales=250)
 - Bike(id=2, name=MX, stock=30)
Sorting using `sales`:
 - Car(id=3, name=M Benz, sales=250)
 - Car(id=1, name=Audi, sales=300)
 - Bike(id=2, name=MX, stock=30)
 - Bike(id=4, name=BH, stock=45)
Sorting using `stock`:
 - Bike(id=2, name=MX, stock=30)
 - Bike(id=4, name=BH, stock=45)
 - Car(id=1, name=Audi, sales=300)
 - Car(id=3, name=M Benz, sales=250)
```

as expected.

Note that there is no need at all for the classes to have any relationship to each other and not even the fields to be compared. Any discrepancies can be resolved at runtime (although this is not desirable).

In particular, classes need not share a common ancestor or interface and fields with different types can also be resolved at runtime.

Comment: it's mentioned in the question not to use the reflection

Comment: Without reflection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 17's pattern matching in `instanceof` makes it a little neater. The last version allows the comparator to be defined in one line, but gives a confusing `NullPointerException` if there is an object in the `List` which is not one of the expected types.

```
public class ComparatorEg {
    static class Car {
        private final int sales;

        Car(int sales) {this.sales = sales;}

        public int getSales() {
            return sales;
        }
    }
    static class Bike {
        private final int sales;

        Bike(int sales) {this.sales = sales;}

        public int getSales() {
            return sales;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> vehicles = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Car(10), new Bike(9), new Car(8)));
        vehicles.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> {
            if (o instanceof Bike b) {
                return b.getSales();
            } else if (o instanceof Car c) {
                return c.getSales();
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("unexpected object: " + o);
            }
        }));
        List<Object> vehicles2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Car(10), new Bike(9), new Car(8), new Object()));
// this will throw an NPE because of the presence of the Object in the list
        vehicles2.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> (o instanceof Bike b) ? b.getSales() : (o instanceof Car c ? c.getSales() : null)));
    }
}
```