# Java, list sorting with reflection

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I want to allow to sort by every field in the class, without having to write switch/ if statements.
My idea was to find the Field that matches given string value by name and then, with Stream API neatly sort. IntelliJ screamed that i need to surround it with try-catch, so it is not so neatly looking, but that's not important, as it does not work.

```
    private List<MyEntity> getSorted(List<MyEntity> list, SearchCriteria criteria) {
        Field sortByField = findFieldInListByName(getFieldList(MyEntity.class), criteria.getSortBy());
        return list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(entity-> {
            try {
                return (MyEntity) sortByField.get(entity);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return entity;
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

In the MyEntity class I have added Comparable interface, but I am not sure what should be in the body of Compare(), as I dont want to specify how to compare objects, because it will change based on the selected sorting.

**EDIT:** Added Entity below:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_management", schema = "mdr")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode

public class MyEntity implements Comparable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;

    @Basic
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "action")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleAction action;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "goal")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleGoal goal;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reporter_id", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
    private UserEntity reporter;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorizer_id", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
    private UserEntity authorizer;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ezd")
    private String ezd;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "is_last")
    private boolean isMostRecent;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** My code based on the @Sweeper solution:

UserEntity (nullable)

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(UserEntity other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return this.getMail().compareTo(other.getMail());
    }
```

Comparator:

```
    public static Comparator getSortComparator(Field sortByField) {
        return Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(entity -> {
            try {
                Object fieldValue = sortByField.get(entity);
                if (!(fieldValue instanceof Comparable<?>) && fieldValue != null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
                }
                return (Comparable) fieldValue;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new MdrCommonException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Show your entity definition for a more precise response please.

Comment: When I used Reflection in Payara/Glassfish, I constantly ran into problems with 'broken' class hierarchies and whatnot. I.e. class hierarhies in Payara were very different from those I actually wrote. I guess this has to do with all the abstraction / bytecode weaving magic that goes on there. Also, theres a gazillion extra properties in each class, be sure to filter those out, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyEntity` should not implement `Comparable`. It is the *fields*, by which you are going to sort the list of `MyEntity` objects, that needs to be `Comparable`. For example, if you are sorting by the field `user`, which is a `UserEntity`, then `UserEntity` is the thing that needs to be comparable, not `MyEntity`.

The lambda's job should just be to check that the fields are indeed `Comparable`, and throw an exception if they are not.

Since you don't know the types of the fields at compile time, however, you'd have to use a raw type here. The `comparing` call would look like this:

```
Comparator.comparing(entity -> {
    try {
        Object fieldValue = sortByField.get(entity);

        // This check still passes if the type of fieldValue implements Comparable<U>, 
        // where U is an unrelated type from the type of fieldValue, but this is the
        // best we can do here, since we don't know the type of field at compile time
        if (!(fieldValue instanceof Comparable<?>) && fieldValue != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field is not comparable!");
        }
        return (Comparable)fieldValue;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, works well, but have also one more question - how to handle null values with such approach? What could be returned in the comparator when the value is null? 
if (fieldValue == null) {return  ?? ;}

Comment: @mintas123 Right now, my answer will treat null as incomparable. Do you want to compare nulls? If so, how do you want them ordered relative to the non-null objects?

Comment: Some values could be null (for example authorizer User), but I would still want to be able to sort the list. I would say that the null should be in order A-Z-null (I have implemented comparable in User enitity)

Comment: Sorry to bother you more, but im getting a null pointer exception with that wrapped. I added to the incomparable check that it only applies to non null values (so it doesnt throw an error), and i have in the User entity in compare method handled when other object is null.

Comment: @mintas123 Oh you handled nulls in `User.compareTo`? No need for `nullsLast` then (dunno why it throws an exception without stack trace). Just change the check to allow nulls: `if (!(fieldValue instanceof Comparable<?>) && fieldValue != null)`

Comment: @mintas123 I just realised I was being dumb - that's not how `nullsLast` works... If `UserEntity` handles nulls, then you don't need anything extra in `getSortComparator`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235616/discussion-between-sweeper-and-mintas123).

Answer (score 1):

You can create automatically comparators for any field of any class [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68518349/1540749) but is better create specific comparators (will be typechecked).

Your entity is a normal class with normal fields then, the usual Java sorting machinery should do the job:

Basically, if you define one comparator for every field (even deep fields into your entity):

```
public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByField1 = comparing(MyEntity::getField1);
public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByField2 = comparing(MyEntity::getField2);
public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByField3 = comparing(MyEntity::getField3);
public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByDeep1 = comparing(a -> a.getField4().getDeep1());
public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByDeep2 = comparing(a -> a.getField4().getDeep2());
public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByDeep3 = comparing(a -> a.getField4().getDeep3());
```

You can sort using complex sorting expressions:

```
data.stream()
        .sorted(ByField2.reversed().thenComparing(ByDeep2))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

a full example could be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<MyEntity> data =
            Stream.of("Row1", "Row2").flatMap(field1 ->
            Stream.of(101, 102).flatMap(field2 ->
            Stream.of(true, false).flatMap(field3 ->
            Stream.of("Row1", "Row2").flatMap(deep1 ->
            Stream.of(101, 102).flatMap(deep2 ->
            Stream.of(true, false).map(deep3 ->
                new MyEntity(field1, field2, field3, new MyDeepField(deep1, deep2, deep3))))))))
            .collect(toList());

    data.stream()
            .sorted(ByField2.reversed().thenComparing(ByDeep2))
            .forEach(System.out::println);

}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class MyDeepField {
    private String deep1;
    private Integer deep2;
    private Boolean deep3;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class MyEntity {
    private String field1;
    private Integer field2;
    private Boolean field3;
    private MyDeepField field4;

    public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByField1 = comparing(MyEntity::getField1);
    public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByField2 = comparing(MyEntity::getField2);
    public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByField3 = comparing(MyEntity::getField3);
    public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByDeep1 = comparing(a -> a.getField4().getDeep1());
    public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByDeep2 = comparing(a -> a.getField4().getDeep2());
    public final static Comparator<MyEntity> ByDeep3 = comparing(a -> a.getField4().getDeep3());

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyEntity{" +
                "field1='" + field1 + '\'' +
                ", field2=" + field2 +
                ", field3=" + field3 +
                ", deep1=" + field4.getDeep1() +
                ", deep2=" + field4.getDeep2() +
                ", deep3=" + field4.getDeep3() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

with output

```
MyEntity{field1='Row1', field2=102, field3=true, deep1=Row1, deep2=101, deep3=true}
MyEntity{field1='Row1', field2=102, field3=true, deep1=Row1, deep2=101, deep3=false}
...
MyEntity{field1='Row2', field2=101, field3=false, deep1=Row2, deep2=102, deep3=true}
MyEntity{field1='Row2', field2=101, field3=false, deep1=Row2, deep2=102, deep3=false}
```

The criteria field into your `SearchCriteria` class is some field of type `Comparator<MyEntity>` or a mapping using an enumeration or parsing string expressions or so...